# Acces a function in a controller through another controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller (called `searchCtrl`) that does a request to a service and then inserts the data from that service into a scope called `movieList`.

I then display the content of the scope `movieList` through a ng-repeat in a template,

```
%li.search_results{"ng-repeat" => "movie in movieList'"}

  .addmovie{"ng-click" => "addMovie()"}
    %span
      Add Movie
  %span.title
    {{ movie.original_title }}
```

In this template I call a function called `addMovie()` which creates a record in my database.

The issue here is that I want to seperate my search function and addMovie function in different controllers. That means that the `addMovie()` function is in a controller called `addMovies`.

So when I click on the `.addmovie` div and fire the `addMovie()` function, it doesn't do anything. So I'm wondering if it is possible to make a connection to the `addMovie()` function inside `addMovies` controller through the `searchCtrl` controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the addMovie() function into a service. That way any controller can access it just by injecting the service into the controller.

```
app.service("movieService",function() {

    this.addMovie = function() {
        //stuff
    }
});
```

Then you would inject the service into your controller like this:

```
app.controller("searchCtrl",function($scope, movieService) {
    //call it here
    movieService.addMovie();
});
```